# Tinder algorithm in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Let's say we have relationships `:LIKED` and `:PASSED` e.g.:

```
(:User1)-[:LIKED]->(:User2)
(:User1)-[:PASSED]->(:User3)
```

I believe the Tinder algorithm does something like this. How would you return a query that:

- get a page of length `20` that consists of
- potential users the current user has not seen yet (not yet `:LIKED` or `:PASSED`)
- with a mix of users that have already `:LIKED` the current user
- and a mix of users that are very attractive (not sure of the best way to do this Elo rating, but this could just be the number of times this user has been `:LIKED` - would be nice to have some sort of trigger that updates the Elo rating = `:LIKED` count on a user whenever a new `:LIKED` relationship is created)

Comment: And what is it you want to accomplish ? Max De Marzi already talked about matchmaking in 2013 (https://maxdemarzi.com/2013/04/19/match-making-with-neo4j/) and while that post does require a couple of updates to the recent Neo4j version the truths still hold.

Comment: I read that post, and it's great, however it just uses filtering in something like a Match.com style based on has and want. The query I am unsure of how to do is Tinder's hook of mixing not seen yet + already liked you + high attractiveness.

Answer (score 0):

So a query like (given a known user to start with) :

```
MATCH (u1:User {id: "known userid"})<-[l1:LIKES]-(u2:User)<-[l2:LIKES]-(u3)
WHERE NOT ((u1)-[]->(u2)) 
WITH DISTINCT u2.name as recommended, count(DISTINCT l2) as attractioncount
WHERE attractioncount > 10
RETURN recommended
```

The **10** is of course an arbitrary value I picked. You decide what the correct recommendation is.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom